# Using apex:commandButton inside relatedList facet to show/hide pageBlocks on a VF page

Tags: visualforce, related-list, rerender, commandbutton, actionsupport

I'm trying to replace the "header" `facet` inside a `relatedList` on my Visualforce page.
Inside the header I want to put a `commandButton` that, when I click it, will hide (via `rendered`) the `pageBlock` that encases the relatedList(s). At the same time, other pageBlocks on the VF page will have their `rendered` boolean flipped so upon `reRender` they will be displayed.
Currently I am getting the `reRender` "flash" when I click the button but the relatedLists still remain and the other pageBlocks remain hidden.

Here is the relatedList pageBlock:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="relatedLists" rendered="{!showRelatedLists}">
    <apex:relatedList list="Injuries__r" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relatedId}">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:form>
            <apex:commandButton value="New Injury Case Detail" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!newCaseDetail}" reRender="accountBlock,relatedLists" />
            </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

below the relatedLists are the other pageBlocks I want to display upon clicking the commandButton:

```
<apex:form id="accountForm">
    <apex:pageBlock mode="detail" id="accountBlock" rendered="{!showCaseDetailForms}">
    {etc...}
```

here is the controller function being called by the `actionSupport`:

```
public PageReference newCaseDetail() {
    showCaseDetailForms = true;
    showRelatedLists = false;
    return null;
}
```

---

Here is the edited code after wrapping the pageblocks in outputpanels:
relatedlists block:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="relatedLists" rendered="{!showRelatedLists}">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:relatedList list="Injuries__r" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relatedId}">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:form>
            <apex:commandButton value="New Injury Case Detail" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!newCaseDetail}" reRender="searchBlock" />
            </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

other pageblocks section:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="searchBlock" rendered="{!showCaseDetailForms}">
<apex:form id="accountForm">
<apex:pageBlock mode="detail" id="accountBlock" rendered="{!showCaseDetailForms}">
{etc...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the portion you want to rerender in an apex:outputpanel. Give that panel the rerender attribute and the id you're trying to rerender.

Comment: Stephen, this solution isn't working for me.
I wrapped the relatedList pageblock in an outputpanel, assigned it the `id` and the `rendered` attribute, then I wrapped the other page blocks in a second outputPanel with the other `id` and `rendered` attribute linked to the boolean in the controller. When I click the commandbutton I see the reRender 'flash' but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you post your edited code?

Comment: Also, you can use the action and rerender attributes of the commandbutton tag. Is there a reason you're using actionsupport?

Comment: Since I was trying to hide the pageBlock section that contains the commandButton while simultaneously showing a different section of the page I thought the asynchronous action of actionSupport would help with this function call and reRender. If I move the action and rerender attributes to the commandButton, when I click the button it doesn't even do the reRender 'flash'.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. **Never rerender the same component in which you have give render condition otherwise it will never work for you.**

```
<apex:form id="accountForm">
```

I think this is your main outer form . try to rerender it from your command button. It will solve your problem.

Also you can do this

```
<apex:commandButton value="New Injury Case Detail"  action="{!newCaseDetail}" reRender="accountForm">
</apex:commandButton>
```

instead of this

```
<apex:commandButton value="New Injury Case Detail" >
       <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!newCaseDetail}" reRender="accountForm" />
 </apex:commandButton>
```

Apply these two changes and your problem will be solved.